# Partial Differentiation of Interpolation Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

New to mma.  I have imported a 3-dimensional array from a CSV file and used the Interpolation function to make the data continuous.  I am now interested in taking the partial derivative of the interpolation function with respect to one of the two variables, but am at a loss for how this is done in the language:

```
timein = Import["file.csv"]
Dimensions[timein]
itime = Interpolation[timein,  Method -> "Spline"]
Plot3D[itime[x, y], {x, 6, 30}, {y, 3, 24}]
D[itime, y]
```

Yields output of:

```
0
```

For the last line of the code.

Comment: Perhaps you will get better answers on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: try `D[itime[x,y], y]`

Comment: why didnt I think of that.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127816/2079

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the correct form ended up being:

```
Derivative[0, 1][itime]
```

to take the first order partial derivative with respect to the second variable (y)